# Changing colors of single column in C3.js stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, c3.js

I am trying to highlight a single set of values in a c3.js stacked bar chart. Following [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JedRW/1/) I can change the color of a single bar in a non-stacked bar, but I can't figure out how to identify the indexes of a single stack.
My JS is:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart1',
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      ['x', "1ST", "2ND", "3RD", "4TH"],
      ['A', 6, 8, 2, 9],
      ['B', 3, 4, 1, 6],
      ['C', 4, 4, 2, 4]

    ],
    type: 'bar',
    groups: [
      ['A', 'B', 'C']
    ],
    colors: {
      A: '#666666',
      B: '#cccccc',
      C: '#428bca',
    },
    order: 'asc'
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'category'
    }
  }
});
```

And the approach of the example is to do:

```
color: function (color, f) {
   return f.index === 4 ? "#dd0" : "#ddd";
}
```

Work in progress [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vabm/kmjpg30c/1/).
How can I get the indexes of the 3 values of a single stack and then use them to change their colors? For example, if I want to highlight "2ND" by changing the colours to a set of reds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from the example here --> 
http://c3js.org/samples/data_color.html

```
    color : function (color, d) {
        return d.index && d.index === 2 ? "#dd0" : color;
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kmjpg30c/3/

`d.index` gives you the index of the stack - however, in your example there is no index 4 as the indexing starts at 0, so you have [0,1,2,3] as a possible range

So test against the index and return a new color if it matches and if it doesn't return the `color` that is originally passed in.

(the `d.index` test is present as the `color` function gets used by other routines that pass in just a string indicating the dataset ("A", "B", "C" in your example), so you need to test for the existence of the fields you need in `d` first.

if you want to highlight just one part of the stack use the `.id` field as well e.g. `d.index === 2 && d.id === "A"`

Comment: Nice, that's getting me closer. How would you change the three colours (i.e., A, B & C) of a single stack (e.g., 3RD)? I need to highlight a full stack dynamically.

Comment: The above code does change all 3 colours in a stack but to the same colour so hard to spot... to make it more noticeable try `d3.interpolateLab(color, "#ff0")(0.8)` instead of just `"#ff0"`

Comment: how can I add different colors to different parts `.id` of the selected stack `.index`?